# BIRT and Web Service Data Sources

Tags: eclipse, birt, eclipse-wtp

I am using BIRT 4.5 and Eclipse/Mars, and attempting to implement the instructions on the following page to create a web services data set:

http://developer.actuate.com/be/documentation/ihub31-dev/DAG/index.html#page/DAG%2Faccessing-data-webservice.10.4.html

The web service I am connecting to is:

http://www.webservicex.net/WeatherForecast.asmx?WSDL

All works according to the Actuate documentation given above until selecting the default options for the SOAP Response, at which point I am getting the following error.

```
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException: XML data source cannot be retrieved. XML data source file is invalid or the file doesn't exist.
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml.ui.wizards.XPathChoosePage.populateXMLTree(XPathChoosePage.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml.ui.wizards.XPathChoosePage.refreshControls(XPathChoosePage.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml.ui.wizards.XPathChoosePage.refresh(XPathChoosePage.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.ws.ui.wizards.XMLTableMappingPage.refresh(XMLTableMappingPage.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.ws.ui.wizards.SOAPResponsePage.getNextPage(SOAPResponsePage.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:878)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:425)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4230)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1491)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1514)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1299)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4072)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3698)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.actions.NewDataSetAction.createNewDataSet(NewDataSetAction.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.actions.NewDataSetAction.run(NewDataSetAction.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4230)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1491)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1514)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1299)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4072)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3698)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```

There are two answers to provide on the "Edit Soap Response" dialog:

1. Select SOAP Response Schema, for which I chose 'Use operation
   response..."
2. Select Sample SOAP response message, for which I left
   blank

This should be a fairly straightforward exercise of connecting BIRT to the weather service, as given by the Actuate example.  Suggestions on the cause of the above stack trace and how to work around it are appreciated.

Comment: For what it is worth, I also spent some time trying to connect to a number of other services (e.g. stock quotes, astronomy, etc.).  All provide the same error.  These latter services work fine with SoapUI, but SoapUI did have some issues with the Weather service (at least tonight).  But the point is, the services which work in SoapUI should work with BIRT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is a bug with BIRT 4.5.x, perhaps prior versions as well.  The details can be found on the Actuate Developer Forum:

http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/37700-connecting-to-the-axis2-echoservice-example/